# Multiple Reporting Services databases in one instance?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Is it possible to have multiple Reporting Services databases in one MSSQL instance?

I have a MSSQL 2008 R2 with RS set to SharePoint Integrated Mode. This RS is in use and can't be changed. I do however need a RS in native mode for the TFS installation to be able to use it.

Am I required to set up a new instance of MSSQL? 
Bonus question: If so, is that permitted under the MS licensing scheme or is it an additional cost?

Answer (score 0):

For the bonus question sql server is licenced per CPU (or CALs), so there is no extra charge per instance.